# Registering a provider programmatically in jersey which implements exceptionmapper

Tags: java, web-services, rest, jersey

How do I register my provider programmatically in jersey which implements the Exceptionmapper provided by jersey API? I don't want to use @Provider annotation and want to register the provider using ResourceConfig, how can I do that?

For example:

```
public class MyProvider implements ExceptionMapper<WebApplicationException> extends ResourceConfig {

     public MyProvider() {
        final Resource.Builder resourceBuilder = Resource.builder();
        resourceBuilder.path("helloworld");

        final ResourceMethod.Builder methodBuilder = resourceBuilder.addMethod("GET");
        methodBuilder.produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN_TYPE)
                .handledBy(new Inflector<ContainerRequestContext, String>() {

            @Override
            public String apply(ContainerRequestContext containerRequestContext) {
                return "Hello World!";
            }
        });

        final Resource resource = resourceBuilder.build();
        registerResources(resource);
    }

    @Override
    public Response toResponse(WebApplicationException ex) {
        String trace = Exceptions.getStackTraceAsString(ex);
        return Response.status(500).entity(trace).type("text/plain").build();
    }
}
```

Is this the correct way to do this?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I'm guessing you don't have a `ResourceConfig`, since you seem to not be sure how to use it. For one, it is not required. If you *do* use it, it should be it's own separate class. There you can register the mapper.

```
public class AppConfig extends ResourceConfig {
    public AppConfig() {
        register(new MyProvider());
    }
}
```

But you are probably using a web.xml. In which case, you can register the provider, with the following `<init-param>`

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>MyApplication</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.classnames</param-name>
        <param-value>
            org.foo.providers.MyProvider
        </param-value>
    </init-param>
</servlet>
```

Have a look at [What exactly is the ResourceConfig class in Jersey 2?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45627178/2587435)
 for more information on different deployment models. There are a few different ways to deploy applications. You can even mix and match (web.xml and ResourceConfig).

Comment: Why `register(new MyProvider())` and not `register(MyProvider.class)`?

Comment: @k-den either way is fine. Unless you want to inject stuff into the mapper, better to register by class. This was just an example. No really reason for the _why_ I chose this way. Just how I was feeling at the time :-)

Answer (score 1):

While @paul-samsotha's answer is correct, still there is implementation trick. I want to share it and hope it will help someone.

a) Implement your mapper:

```
public class MyExceptionMapper implements ExceptionMapper<Throwable>, ResponseErrorMapper {
    ...
```

b) make sure you declare generic type, otherwise your mapper will never be called

```
public class MyExceptionMapper implements ExceptionMapper/* no generic declaration */, ResponseErrorMapper {
    ...
```

and may trigger

```
javax.ws.rs.ProcessingException: Could not find exception type for given ExceptionMapper class: class com...MyExceptionMapper.
```

c) Register it as resource:

```
ResourceConfig config = new ResourceConfig();
config.register(new MyExceptionMapper());
```

or

```
config.register(MyExceptionMapper.class);
```

d) make sure you enforce processing errors as well:

```
config.setProperties(new LinkedHashMap<String, Object>() {{
    put(org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerProperties.PROCESSING_RESPONSE_ERRORS_ENABLED, true);
}});
```

Answer (score -1):

If you're using Spring and want to register the providers programmatically based on the presence of `@Path` and `@Provider` annotation you can use the following technique

```
@Component
public class JerseyConfig extends ResourceConfig {

  @Autowired
  private ApplicationContext applicationContext;

  @PostConstruct
  public init() {

    applicationContext.getBeansWithAnnotation(Path.class).values().forEach(
      component -> register(component.getClass())
    );
    applicationContext.getBeansWithAnnotation(Provider.class).values().forEach(
      this::register
    );
  }
}
```