# How to filter xml object in typescript

Tags: angular, xml, typescript

I have `xml` object got from `xml` files(not rest API) in `Angular` application and don't want to convert it to `json` format, just I want to use it as `xml`.
When I apply filter on it, its not working

```
var records = obj.filter((x) => x.Name.includes("Samsung"))
```

here `records` is empty.

Comment: I don't think this is possible. You need to parse the xml beforehand.

Comment: Is your xml coming out of a web service? If so try changing web service call requesting type? You may be lucky by appending .json or .xml. Here's how I did it for a mobile app calling a Java web service.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47479511/jax-rs-jersey-2-implementation-content-negotiation-with-url-extension-xml-or

Comment: @JGFMK - I have xml files in assest folder. From there getting xml object.

Comment: Did you mean asset folder? If so trace that back a level.. How did that get populated?